# AppCompat / Chromecast in Android-L Preview

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, chromecast, android-appcompat

**Situation:**

I'm currently building a new version of my app for Android L and am also in the process of Chromecast integration.
The app works fine, as long as I extend Theme.Material with my custom style, but doesn't show the Cast button.

**Problem:**

As soon as I change to Theme.AppCompat, it gives me the error:

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

and the same goes for the the Holo Theme as well.

Here's my **build.gradle** (The libs folder is empty btw.):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 'android-L'
    targetSdkVersion 'android-L'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

Here is the relevant part of the **values/styles.xml**:

```
<style name="SK" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

used to work with Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar

and the **values-v21/styles.xml**:

```
<style name="SK" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

used to wirk with Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar

I already cleaned and rebuild the project, but it always goes back to showing me errors about a missing parent.
As far as I could gather from similar questions, all relevant libraries are included and all use the newest version available.
I also tried manually adding the libraries to the libs/ folder with no success.
My SDK manager shows that everything is installed and up to date.

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

It was actually rather simple. I referred to Theme.AppCompat with the android namespace, but should have left it out, so, instead of

```
@android:style/Theme.AppCompat
```

it should be

```
@style/Theme.AppCompat
```

This did show another error initially, about "Theme" not being found, but it compiled non the less.